# Save child before parent without duplication c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, asp.net-core

Let's say We have class parent

```
    public class Parent {
int Id {get;set;}
Child child {get;set;}
}
```

And class child

```
public class Child {
    int Id {get;set;}
    string Info {get;set;}
    }
```

I create an object of child and save it db

```
Child child = new Child();
  dbContext.Child.Add(child);
                    dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

then I create a parent object and assign the created child to parent object(to use it later)

```
 Parent parent = new Parent();
      parent.child=child;
       dbContext.Parent.Add(parent);
         dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

The problem after saving the the parent object in the db, I get a duplicated object of child in child Class in the db.
Note that I'm using sql Server as db.

**I want to assign the object of child to parent and when I save parent in the db, the parent don't save the child again, Any solution please?**

Comment: Your Child object inside Parent is probably populated and EF is adding it when adding the Parent record. If you don't want to add Child and Parent at the same time, make Child null inside of Parent.

Comment: I need to use it later so it can't be null in my case

Comment: Can't you skip adding child to dbContext and saving it. Instead continue with adding parent to dbContext and saving it.

Comment: You're adding it twice. Only add it once. Either add the nested object to Parent and save Parent or make Child null in Parent and add Child separately.

Comment: does the child have a unique id or primary key that cannot be duplicated?

Comment: @IsaacIkusika yes it does have a primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I found is to call the save method of the dbcontext only once, (I called it when saving the parent only) otherwise it will save it twice in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Parent parent = new Parent();
var existingChild = dbContext.Child.Find(child.id);
if (existingChild != null){
    parent.child = existingChild;
}
dbContext.Parent.Add(parent);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Didn't work, still the parent duplicate the child when saving it

Comment: @Akrem you are sure that child exist in db?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @SerPecchia Yes, the child exists in db

Answer (score 1):

To avoid insertion again if it's already there you can set dbContext as [Unchanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2016/august/data-points-ef-core-change-tracking-behavior-unchanged-modified-and-added) after attaching the child object to the context.

Add the following code after the saving child object.

```
dbContext.Entry(child).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work.
The only solution I found is to call the save method of context only once, (I called it when saving the parent only) otherwise it will save it twice in the database.